# What is the way to solve the problem of sox?

Tags: sox

I want to use sox to repair the sound file. But sox cannot be run. Please answer how to solve this error. Thank in advance!

```
/usr/bin/sox -r 44.1k anger.wav outfile.wav
```

> bash: /usr/bin/sox: No such file or directory

Comment: try **sox --version** - what do you get?

Comment: sox --version
bash: /usr/bin/sox: No such file or directory

Comment: But, which sox
/usr/bin/sox

Comment: when you run **which sox** - what do you get

Comment: which sox  /usr/bin/sox

Comment: have a look at this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/560666/cant-run-sox-no-such-file-or-directory) on superuser.com..

Comment: I have restarted and run.But the error exist.

Comment: locate sox
/lib/modules/4.8.0-22-generic/vdso/vdsox32.so